# Add exception in rewriterule nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Basically I have this rewriterule:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /index.php?goto=$1 break;
    rewrite ^/page/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /index.php?goto=$1&page=$2 break;
}
```

And works like a charm. The problem is that I have a folder named images (in the same directory of the location, in the root) that I want to avoid to be included in the rewriterule.

When I visit domain.com/images, it gives me the 404 not found error (because is interpreted in the rewriterule) but if I add index.php at the end (the index of the images folder) it works.

Any idea to resolve this issue?

It's not a problem of configuration of nginx, because without rewriterule domain.com/images works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a negative lookahead to exclude `/images` in the regex:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(?!images)([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /index.php?goto=$1 break;
    rewrite ^/page/([A-Za-z]+)/?$ /index.php?goto=$1&page=$2 break;
}
```